# Extending Magento API - Invalid Path

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to extend the Magento API - I've followed the steps from most tutorials and have done the following. 
I keep getting an invalid resource path error from magenta when I try to call any of the extended api methods.

Create a Module XML descriptor in app/etc/modules called Woe_Services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Woe_Services>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Woe_Services>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I created a corresponding directory structure:

```
-app
--code
---local
----Woe
-----Services

------etc
-------|api.xml
-------|config.xml

------Model
------- Catalog
-------- Product
--------- Attribute
---------- Api.php
```

My config.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Woe_Services>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Woe_Services>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_attribute_api>Woe_Services_Model_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Api</product_attribute_api>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

My api.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <catalog_product_attribute translate="title"
                module="catalog">
                <title>Product attributes API</title>
                <model>catalog/product_attribute_api</model>
                <acl>catalog/product</acl>
                <methods>
                    <create translate="title" module="catalog">
                        <title>Create new product attribute</title>
                        <acl>catalog/product/attribute/create</acl>
                    </create>
                    <delete translate="title" module="catalog">
                        <title>Delete product attribute</title>
                        <acl>catalog/product/attribute/delete</acl>
                    </delete>
                    <addoptions translate="title" module="catalog">
                        <title>Add attribute options</title>
                        <acl>catalog/product/attribute/addoptions</acl>
                    </addoptions>
                </methods>
            </catalog_product_attribute>
        </resources>
        <acl>
            <resources>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

Finally, Api.php file is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * @category    Ajzele
 * @package     Ajzele_Mapy
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) Branko Ajzele (http://activecodeline.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Catalog product attribute api
 *
 * @category   Ajzele
 * @package    Ajzele_Mapy
 * @author     Branko Ajzele <ajzele@gmail.com>
 */
class Woe_Services_Model_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Api extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Api
{
  /**
     * Create new product attribute.
     *
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @param array $attributeData
     * @param string|int $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function create($attributeName, $attributeData, $store = null)
    {
    // create product attribute
        $installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup('core_setup');
        $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeName, $attributeData);

    // get product attribute id
        $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeName);

    return $attribute->getId();
    }

   /**
     * Create attribute options
     *
     * @param string $attributeId
     * @param array $attributeOptions
     * @return int
     */
    public function addoptions($attributeId, $attributeOptions)
    {
    $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($attributeOptions); $i++) {
        $option = array();
        $option['attribute_id'] = $attributeId;
        $option['value'][$value][0] = $attributeOptions[$i];

        $setup->addAttributeOption($option);
    }

    return true;
    }

   /**
     * Delete product attribute.
     *
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @param string|int $store
     * @return int
     */
    public function delete($attributeName, $store = null)
    {
        $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeName);

        if (!$attribute) {
            $this->_fault('not_exists');
        }

        try {
            $attribute->delete();
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_fault('not_deleted', $e->getMessage());

            return false;
        }

    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the following structure:
`-app
--code
---local
----Woe_Services`

Or it might be even better to name it just as `WoeServices`. Underscores have special meaning in Zend and hence in Magento on which it is built, and might be a cause of the problem.

Comment: I have not tried that, however, I have examined many other modules / extensions and they're mostly using the same convention.

Comment: I am using SOAP. Also, I'm using Magja - a Java adapter to Magento. http://code.google.com/p/magja/. However, not sure that should be too relevant.

Comment: Fixed it - Make sure you turn rewrite on in the server config.

Comment: @Evan: maybe close this question?

Comment: @Evan Klein: Please add your solution as an answer below (yes that works) and then select it as the answer. This helps to mark the question as solved and others who might run into the problem will see the solution more prominently. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Make sure you turn rewrite on in the server config.

*Evan Klein May 31 at 17:55*

Answer (score 0):

If you are using soap the you are missing a critical file called wsdl.xml you need to define that module inside your module etc/ folder; the file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <complexType name="TestSvcEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="testArg" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
            <complexType name="testArrayOfString">
                <complexContent>
                    <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
                    </restriction>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>                        
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="testRequest">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="param1" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="testResponse">
        <part name="test_out" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>     
    <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <operation name="test">
            <documentation>Test</documentation>
            <input message="typens:testRequest" />
            <output message="typens:testResponse" />
        </operation>        
    </portType>
    <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="test">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>        
    </binding>
    <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

You can always check your API http://www.yoursite.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1 that will show all your ip available methods.

Also check that:

1. Your model appears and is enabled under the advanced tab
2. Clear your cache
3. Depending on your server config check the /tmp folder for a cache version of the wsdl.

Let me know how it goes and if that solves the issue.

Cheers!